# How can I stop 3D conversions to 2D coordinates creating "ghost" coordinates on the other side?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am currently converting the 3D coordinates of an object to 2D coordinates, and then drawing 2D text over them (at the moment, the object name):

```
public static int[] getScreenCoords(double x, double y, double z) {
    FloatBuffer screenCoords = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
    IntBuffer viewport = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer modelView = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projection = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelView);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
    boolean result = GLU.gluProject((float) (x), (float) y, (float) (z), modelView, projection, viewport, screenCoords);
    if (result) {
        return new int[] { (int) screenCoords.get(0), (int) screenCoords.get(1)};
    }
    return null;
}
```

This works correctly. Names are successfully placed above objects.

[image]

The problem is that if I look in the opposite direction, I see "ghost" names on the other side:
[image]

How can I stop this problem? Is there some way I can detect if I'm looking away from them and not render them?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Thank you, your suggestion was correct and it solved the issue. Just the elegant solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the sign of the screen's z-value `screenCoords.get(2)` (look/front is in negative z-direction):

```
...
boolean result = GLU.gluProject((float) (x), (float) y, (float) (z), modelView, projection, viewport, screenCoords);
if (result && screenCoords.get(2) < 0) {
    return new int[] { (int) screenCoords.get(0), (int) screenCoords.get(1)};
}
return null;
```

Comment: For some reason for me, if it's positive it is *not* in the cameras' field of view. Anyway, the issue is solved now and since it works I've accepted your answer. Thank you for the help.